# How to get IP Address of a Website?(Windows phone 7.0)

Tags: windows-phone-7, dns, ip-address, web-hosting

Windows Phone 7.0 have not support IPAddress Class, IPHostEntry Class, and Dns Class.

Have any other class to get IP Address of a Website on Windows phone 7.0?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you want to get IP from a URL in a native WP7 app. There is no API at the moment. What you could do is to build a webservice(even webservice is a big word) that will return the IP. The simplest solution is to pass get parameter mywebsite.com/index.html?url=http://www.google.com and then call nslookup, grep Address and display it. use WebClient Class to download the string. voila.

Comment: Thank you! i will build a webservice that return IP.